# Entity Provider: No encoder has been configured for account

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to setup a login system using the Doctrine Entity Provider but I always get this error:

```
No encoder has been configured for account "Prefix\MainBundle\Entity\Admin"
```

Here is my setup:

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Prefix\MainBundle\Entity\Admin:
            algorithm:        sha1
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: PrefixMainBundle:Admin, property: username }

    firewalls:
        administrators:
            pattern:    ^/admin/
            anonymous:  ~
            provider:   administrators
            form_login:
                login_path:  /admin/login
                check_path:  /admin/login_check

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I have the Entity created and implements the UserInterface but I can't make it work, it'd great if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: When doing what action do you get this error?

Comment: Always on login action

Comment: I've found the problem. The name of the encoder didn't match the name of the entity in the provider, but as a change the name for the example the error was not there. Sorry

Comment: Don't be sorry, we all make mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the provider to be under the form login:

```
        form_login:
            login_path:  /admin/login
            check_path:  /admin/login_check
            provider:     administrators
```

I am assuming you the error when trying to login using a form.

And while not directly related, you should replace your login paths with named routes.

Comment: You mean under the form_login directly? Is it possible that being under login and check paths doesn't work correctly? I can't try it right now, but I'll tell you if that solves the problems. Thanks!!

Comment: I mean that it just needs to go somewhere under form_login.  Right now you have it under administrators.  So the default provider is being used which means the default encoder is being used and hence the problem.  Your paths are working otherwise it would never have reached the point of needing an encoder.

Comment: I've put the provider line under the form_login but the error is still appearing. Do I need to put the same name in the encoder definition than the provider and firewall names?